# Can I get a grammatical breakdown of "通りゃんせ"?

Tags: grammar, verbs, dialects, archaic-language

So, I recently learned that there's this song called [「通りゃんせ」](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%80%9A%E3%82%8A%E3%82%83%E3%82%93%E3%81%9B), which I guess would be familiar to all of you who have lived in Japan.

The grammatical form "通りゃんせ" (and later in the song, "[下]{くだ}しゃんせ") is completely unfamiliar to me. The Japanese Wikipedia article for the song gives 通りなさい as a translation, which is good to know, but I would like to know more about this form. I figure that it is either archaic or at least non-標準語, judging from the use of じゃ as a copula and 通しゃせぬ as the negation of, uh, I guess 通す or some related verb.

Comment: 「通る」の連用形＋「やんす」の命令形だと思います。
https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%82%84%E3%82%93%E3%81%99-650011

Comment: I would not call this auxiliary verb "archaic" because (1) it is found in any modern Japanese dictionary and (2) it is still used actively by quite a few people as a humorous sentence-ender 「～～でやんす」.  In the imperative form, however, that song is just about the only place you will hear it.  http://search.yahoo.co.jp/search?p=%E3%81%A7%E3%82%84%E3%82%93%E3%81%99&aq=-1&oq=&ei=UTF-8&fr=top_ga1_sa&x=wrt

Comment: Ah, I see! I didn't think to view it as 通り plus やんせ because of how the り and や had become りゃ. That definitely answers my question, if either of you wants to post an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"通りゃんせ" is a colloquial contraction of "通りやんせ", which is masu-stem(連用形) of "通る"="通り" with imperative form(命令形) of "やんす"="やんせ". Also, 下しゃんせ is "下す" with "やんす".

See [やんす](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%82%84%E3%82%93%E3%81%99-650011)